# Can we have a warning message on creation of new tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I find it very easy to mistakenly make new tags by mistyping an existing tag's name. I've also had the issue where I somehow changed the very first tag in the list, when adding a tag a new tag to a question. For example [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/5024/revisions) [football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) was changed to [efootball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efootball) when I added the [equipment](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag to the question, and [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/25099/revisions) [basketball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basketball) became [pbasketball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pbasketball) when adding [postseason](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postseason). For some reason the first letter of the new tag I added to the list, also got applied to the first tag that was already in the list.

It'd be nice to have a pop up letting us know we're creating a new tag, just in case it wasn't the intended goal, specially since it's a [functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897) of SE.

Comment: Confirming this is on the CM's backlog, and we'll update y'all once a CM gets assigned to dig into this :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just flipped the corresponding site setting, so the new tag creation pop-up warning should now be enabled.

Comment: Looks good on the main site. Is there any chance we can turn it on the meta as well?

Comment: Yup, @alamoot — done!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a good idea to me; creating tags should be a rarer thing, in any event, so not a big deal to have a small barrier to doing it, and it might discourage people creating needless tags as a bonus.

Comment: Have we made any progress towards this?

Comment: I'll ping the CMs about it, since it seems like we have a consensus more-or-less!